# Is it "bash" that changes the foreground process group of a terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

Let's say I have opened a terminal window that uses `bash`. The process group that `bash` belongs to is the foreground process group of the terminal.

Now let's say I opened `cat` in the terminal, what will happen is that a new process group will be created and `cat` will belong to this process group, **and this process group will now become the foreground process group of the terminal**.

When `cat` terminates and execution returns to `bash`, **the process group that `bash` belongs to will again becomes the foreground process group of the terminal**.

My question is: how did the foreground process group of the terminal changed in these two times, is it `bash` that changed it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Quoting [this answer by Gilles on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232278/70524):

> The terminal's associated PGID can be set by the
>   [`tcsetpgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tcsetpgrp.html)
>   function, which is called by the shell when it starts an external
>   program in the foreground, or moves a job into the foreground with
>   `fg`.